# Multiple user roles with different attributes

Tags: mysql, database-design, performance, permissions, role, query-performance

I need to design a database that has multiple users, with multiple roles. For instance, a user can be an admin, company, employee, or customer. Each user can have any number of these roles. Right now I have tables that look like this:
[image: Database Design]

Right now, it seems as though when a user logs in, we will have to return from the "What role(s) is/are the user?" query in order to get the information out of the correct table (ex. admins, employees, customers, or companies). I would like to be able to query one time and grab all of a users information. Is this possible, if so how could it be done?

To sum up the problem:
Notice that their are two independent sections (not connected by any lines to the other section). I need a way to connect those.

Comment: Do you have any queries you've tried so far to get this info?

Comment: No, because I cannot see how it would be possible. It's not the syntax that I am worried about, it is more the theory behind it.

Comment: Your sections are connected, but your diagramming tool doesn't see it because you didn't define the referential integrity in your DDL (or your modeling tool) properly.  Note that every specialty role has a key of `user_id`.  This should be FK to `Users.id`.  In other words, `Users` is a super-type and `admins`, `employees`, `customers`, etc. are all subtypes related 1:0,1 to the super-type.

Comment: Hi @JoelBrown. I want the first and last names when a user logged in. How can i do that without knowing subtable names?

Comment: @Arash You can't. Not with the design illustrated in the question.  A good use of the super-type / sub-type would put common attributes in the super-type. If it had been done that way then you would have access to the first and last names directly from the super-type (Users table). Alternatively a view could be defined which selects these common attributes from all the sub-types.  At the same time, one must ask, if you are authorized to use the database, why wouldn't you know the sub-type table names?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @JoelBrown. I want to display the full name of a logged in user in the next page. The user can select a role in the login page. But i don't want to hard code subtable names. When the user select a role, i want to call a interface method to fetch the first and last names from the relevant subtable. is it possible with this design? i don't know if it's correct; i think the first and last names belong to, for example, the `customer` table not the `user` table.

Comment: About my last sentence. Imagine there is `employee` table. Some of them can have a account in the system but all of them have the first and last names. Then i need a table, for example, the `SystemUser` table that doesn't have the first and last names.

Comment: @Arash the design in this question is not well suited to your desired purpose. The name information should be in the common user table not in each of the sub-types.  It is not possible to get first and last name before knowing what sub-type they are in. It is also a problem because they could be in more than one sub-type. What if an employee is also a customer?  They could have two different names then, which is not desirable. You are better off making a new design that meets your needs.